# StackExchange DreamForce meetup?

Tags: discussion

So this stack exchange is in a relatively uncommon situation where we have a built in annual conference.

While I'm still not 100% sure if I'll be there or not I imagine a good amount of us will - is there any interest in some sort of meetup?

Comment: Another reason to feel disappointed that I'm not going to Dreamforce :) However I'll be pushing for this next Cloudforce London!

Comment: This is a great idea and I'd love to...but unfortunately I'm not going. :( A bunch of my co-workers are though...stop by Booth #3 and mention me.  Maybe they'll have some schwag for you. ;).  Next year, for me.

Comment: Good idea. Would definitely join, if I'd be attending dreamforce. Which, I'm not. (Maybe next year)

Comment: +1 Great Idea! But I won't be going unfortunately! Have a good time!

Answer (score 5):

Yes. I vote for trying to meetup Monday night, pre-conference.

**Update**

The consensus is to meet at [Thirsty Bear](http://www.thirstybear.com/) on Thursday @8p.m.

Comment: I might be able to make it to that - preferred venue???

Comment: I might also be able to make this, though probably not for a full evening due to DF12 prep. But any ideas for a venue?

Comment: Nothing specific, yet (I don't know the area that well.) Maybe try to find a good brew pub near Moscone?

Comment: Doh, Monday I definitely can't do :(

Comment: [Thirsty Bear](http://www.thirstybear.com/)?

Comment: Do you have to rub it in? Loved that place :)

Comment: I'm open to Tuesday or Thursday.

Comment: Tuesday or Thursday works for me as well. Thursday might be easier.

Comment: So it turns out I'm already going to an event at the Thirsty Bear on Monday night, the IRC/IRL meetup at the House of Shields on Tuesday, and the Homebrew/Pliny meetup at ROE on Thursday :-o

Comment: So Thursday at Thirsty Bear? 8ish? (Sorry, @metadaddy.)

Comment: Thursday works for me!

Comment: Works for me — Mike want to edit the answer so it's nice and clear? :)

Comment: Envy @ all_of_you_who_are_going !!!   Need already to plan for next DF in Europe !

Comment: I'm there...see you there...

Comment: I'll see if I can drop in after the Homebrew/Pliny do - it starts at 7pm.

Comment: Great - looking forward to it!