# Dreamforce '13 - Let's meet!

Tags: discussion

Stealing an idea from last year ([StackExchange DreamForce meetup?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/stackexchange-dreamforce-meetup)), I was curious if there was any interest in meeting up this year again. I realize it is early still, too early to really get something concrete in place, but I am trying to gauge interest to see if it would make sense to try and organize something.

I would love to meet some of you. We have an incredibly talented bunch of Salesforce admins/developers/users on this site. So, if you are interested in meeting up, upvote this question and leave a comment/answer. Details will be set closer to the date of the event.

---

EDIT: Well, it has been slightly over a month and there is only about a month to go until Dreamforce. Does anyone have any suggestions on where/when we should meet?

---

A few of us are meeting tomorrow morning (11/21) at 7am at Mel's Diner if anyone is interested.

Comment: I am just a simple developer and junior member of this great site but I would love the opportunity to meet you guys at DF!

Comment: Yes. That would be great.

Comment: Sounds great! Count me in

Comment: Unfortunately, for the eighth year running, I won't be making it.

Comment: I'm in! I'll be flying in Saturday.

Comment: Great idea Jesse, count me in! :)

Comment: @sfdcfox That really sucks, maybe some kind of Google Hangout is in order, perhaps a good idea in general throughout the year for us all to discuss topics on our minds for growing this site?

Comment: Loved seeing you guys at Mel's this morning. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 16):

Yep, I'm interested, and this would probably be a good place to reveal that [LaceySnr](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/laceysnr) and I are working on a Salesforce StackExchange theater session (to be scheduled), so that will definitely be a rallying point!

Comment: That's awesome! I will definitely be there to support SFSE!

Comment: Wow, that's cool Daddy!

Comment: @metadaddy do please keep us updated about that session!

Comment: Much chances that I will attend DF13 as well

Comment: Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange
Monday, November 18th: 5:30 PM - 6:00 PM

Comment: Very cool idea, please keep us posted! :)

Comment: I attended this session and it was a good intro to the site.

Comment: Thanks @RichardN! Apologies for having to leg-it straight away, had an MVP event that was supposed to start at 6:15!

Comment: Recording of the metadaddy/LaceySnr session: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYcklcNLL-Q

Answer (score 6):

Tentative plan - beers after the SFSE session?

Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange Monday, November 18th: 5:30 PM - 6:00 PM

Comment: Sounds like an idea!

Comment: Argggh, thats the MVP event evening.... if the tentative plan changes, let me know! :)

Comment: Beers **between** the session and the MVP evening. What could possibly go wrong? ;-)

Comment: Beer always sounds like a good idea! This seems as good a time as any!

Comment: Count me in.  Let us know if the plans change

Answer (score 4):

This will be my first dreamforce. And I am super excited, thrilled. SFSE ftw.

Answer (score 4):

San Francisco here I come !!!

Just got approval to attend.

- Still a project that is open, that might cancel this at the last minute, but I think positive @!!@!@!@!@!

Can someone create a Meetup/other way to get organize?

Answer (score 3):

Definitely interested.  That would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Would love to meet at DF. I wonder if there is some SFSE swag we can all wear to find each other.