# Dreamforce '13 Sessions: Does anything look particularly good? / Meetup

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

I've just started to rummage through the Dreamforce '13 sessions, and I'm curious to know what  everybody thinks about the sessions.

Thoughts?

---

Also, there has been talk about [meeting up at Dreamforce](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/440/dreamforce-lets-meet).  I propose at least one meetup before/after one of the Keynotes (perhaps the Dev Keynote).  Whatcha think?

**EDIT:**

If I see any sessions that appear strikingly cool, I'll post 'em here FYI.  Please do the same :{D

Comment: first question is hugely broad and very personally different.  Attend the session about this very website/community, odds are many of us will attend:  Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange

Comment: "Pushing the Boundaries: The Best of Salesforce StackExchange"   That's what I'm talking about!