# Dreamforce '14 - Let's Meet!

Tags: discussion, dreamforce

The last two years there has been a meet and greet for the Salesforce StackExchange community at Dreamforce ([2012](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/605), [2013](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/440/605)). We have just about 3 months until this year's Dreamforce, so I wanted to get a topic up for discussion on what we can do this year before all of the other excitement takes over.

Last year I had a [fantastic time at Dreamforce](http://jessealtman.com/2013/11/dreamforce-13-recap/) and one big reason for that was meeting up with some awesome SFSE members:

> **Salesforce StackExchange Breakfast**
>
> One of my favorite moments of the entire conference was the Salesforce
>   StackExchange breakfast. Unfortunately, I was unable to attend the
>   StackExchange session Matt Lacey and Pat Patterson did on Monday (when
>   drinks were originally planned), but after meeting up with Ritesh
>   Aswaney on Wednesday, it was decided to have a SFSE breakfast the
>   following morning. With a few quick tweets, we were able to get a few
>   of the guys together. Hopefully next year we can plan this more than
>   12 hours in advance and get more people involved. Either way, it was a
>   memorable experience and great to meet some ridiculously talented
>   individuals.
>
> [image: Salesforce StackExchange Breakfast]
>
> [Andy
>   Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett), [Jesse
>   Altman](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/605/jesse-altman), [Daniel
>   Hoechst](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/87/daniel-hoechst), [Peter
>   Knolle](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/154/peter-knolle), [Steven
>   Herod](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/94/steven-herod), [Zach
>   McElrath](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/398/zachelrath) (left to right) [Pat
>   Patterson](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/67/metadaddy) (behind camera)

With that in mind, I wanted to propose that we try to have another meetup. There is so much competition for time at night during Dreamforce, so I wanted to suggest we once again have a Salesforce StackExchange breakfast. It worked well last year, and I could see it working well again.

Last year we went to [Mel's Drive-In on Mission St](http://www.melsdrive-in.com/hoursandlocations/missionstreet.html). They have really good food, so I see that working again unless someone has a better idea (it is also really close to Moscone Center). How would people feel about 7am or 7:30am on Wednesday October 15th? I realize it is early so this date may change if the night before has the concert or something. I want to find a date/time that works for everyone but that may be impossible.

Let me know what you think. Any interest?

EDIT: Please view the answer below from Daniel Hoechst for updated info regarding the breakfast. It will not be at Mel's, but rather Sears Fine Foods. Make sure you register if you are attending.

Comment: What a good looking group of people! ;)

Comment: Totally up for this :) Was gutted I couldn't make the breakfast last year, got smashed by the Hackathon that week!

Comment: I'm in, and I think breakfast is a winner, as long as there is plenty of coffee around.

Comment: I'm in! Early morning breakfast is best for me too. At this point, I don't have anything scheduled, so Wednesday is as good a day as any. The earlier we get to Mel's, the easier it is to get a table.

Comment: Sounds like a good time! I went to Mels last year and it was hands down the best breakfast I had at DF. Wednesday works for me.

Comment: I don't know my schedule yet, but I'd love to meet up with the StackExchange gang.

Comment: Sounds good. This will be my first time attending Dreamforce. It would be good to get some tips from previous attendees.

Comment: No Dreamforce for me this year :(

Comment: Oh this sounds like fun. I may join you guys ;)

Comment: I'm in; thanks for organizing!

Comment: Sounds awesome.  Count me in!

Comment: I am deffo up for this too, and agree a breakfast is best... (though that said, they are becoming as popular and in-demand as the evening parties these days - ever reducing the net-sleep achieved at Dreamforce each year)!! SFSE would be a top breakie choice for me though :D

Comment: I'll try to attend, if I can drag myself out of bed that early.

Comment: Count me in! I'm there!

Comment: I'm in as well --- agreed with @LaceySnr that it will be easier this year with the Hackathon NOT occurring during Dreamforce.

Comment: One thing...if it is a large group, I know a place we can reserve off of Union Square. Although, I can understand why Mel's would be a popular choice.

Comment: I'd love to do this.

Comment: Yep nice idea, great company and great food! Count me in! :-)

Comment: +1 - I would love to join, is there a page where we can RSVP and track who all are joining?

Comment: Is this open to any nice friendly SFSE fan?

Comment: +1 Great Idea! I'll be there!

Comment: @Dominic this is open to everyone!

Comment: @Peter we will wait until closer, but we may have to take you up on that offer. Last year there was only a handful of us, but if everyone commenting really wants to come, we could end up having a much larger group.

Comment: Any chance there'll be a 2016 meetup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make communication a bit easier, I spun up an Eventbrite event for breakfast at Dreamforce. Signup there. If we get lots of interest, we can move the location. I can send out updates from Eventbrite as well.

UPDATE: Due to a great level of interest, we are moving this meet up to Sears Fine Foods.

[SFSE at Dreamforce](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/sfse-df14-tickets-13143531657)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like we have 14 people interested so far.

Comment: We are up to 22 registered!

Comment: Another year that I can't make it. Hopefully next year

Comment: Just signed up. See you there in a few fays

Comment: A bunch of us are bringing shorts and stickers!

Comment: Err, shirts not shorts. Shorts would be cool too...

Comment: Great to see everyone on Wednesday! @DanielHoechst - did you post the pics somewhere?

Comment: I posted them on Twitter. I'll see if I can get them here too.