# Congrats to the newest MVPs

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to take a moment to congratulate the [Summer 15 MVPs](https://t.co/E6pkiLnX4I). Two of the first time MVPs are quite active here. I'm of course speaking of @DanielBallinger and @Bachovski. Kudos to the two of you, well deserved.

Congrats as well to the MVPs who were re-awarded that continue to support this place. SF.SE wouldn't be the same without the extensive knowledge, expertise and experience all of the new, present and past MVPs share with us. Since there are so many of you, I won't attempt to mention all of you by name for fear of omitting someone. Instead, I'll just say "Thank You".

Comment: Congrats to all MVPs and Thanks to every contributor to this community.. everyone here is awesome :-)

Comment: Congrats to @DanielBallinger and @Bachovski! Very well deserved.

Comment: Huge congrats Daniel and Bachovski

Comment: Congrats Daniel and Bachovski

Comment: Congrats all around friends!!

Comment: Kudos Guys...Very well deserved recognition !

Answer (score 16):

Thanks Cal! I look forward to continuing to contribute to the community.

We should definitely do a repeat of [Dreamforce '14 - Let's Meet!](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/705/dreamforce-14-lets-meet) again this year for anyone going to Dreamforce '15. It was great to meet people in person.

Daniel Hoechst has posted [Dreamforce '15 Let's Meet!](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1986/102)

Answer (score 16):

Thanks everyone!

I echo @DanielBallinger and I'm looking forward to meeting with everyone from this community who'll be attending Dreamforce '15.

Perhaps we should organise something on eventbrite/meetup?

Since I'm a Dreamforce and San Francisco virgin, I'll be awaiting comms for a meetup!