# Dreamforce '15 Let's Meet!

Tags: discussion

The idea has been batted around a few times on Twitter. Let's do another get together at Dreamforce this year. Last year we did an early breakfast at Sears Fine Foods in Union Square. They have a big basement space that worked out well. Should we do the same thing again? Or should we shoot for an evening get together?

I've begun researching Sears again for availability.

Comment: Looks like Sears doesn't book for breakfast anymore. I'm looking into Lori's now.

Comment: I'd definitely be up for this! Only constraint I (and probably others) have is a time that's compatible with being an expo exhibitor.

Comment: I was disappointed I couldn't join you guys last year, but I'll definitely be there this year.

Comment: I'm interested. Breakfast near the start of conference as suggested by Keith C would be good.

Comment: I am absolutely in again this year.  It was great meeting everyone last year, and look forward to it again.

Comment: "Sears Fine Foods in Union Square". I'm interested that you don't see a need to specify the town or city, or indeed the country!

Comment: @TRiG I thought that was a given as we are talking about Dreamforce. San Francisco!

Comment: Just registered. Looking forward to meet you all in real life.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We now have a time (Tuesday at 7am), meeting location (Lori's Diner), and a sponsor (Salesforce Developer Relations)!

Register for the event on [Eventbrite](https://www.eventbrite.com/e/sfse-df15-registration-17834907689). Space is limited, so only register if you can make it. There will be a waitlist if we get more than 30 registered, but I'm hoping we can accommodate everyone.

Comment: Mmm, Breakfast.

Comment: Yeah! I'm signed up! I will have to get my Sears fix at another time. :-)

Comment: \*Sigh\* -- waitlisted.

Comment: I released all the waitlisted slots.

Comment: Anything for 2016?

Comment: I'd love to do it, but I've overextended myself the last few Dreamforces. Maybe someone will pick up the mantle?

Answer (score 20):

**IMPORTANT** - See the [actual event details in Daniel H's answer](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1993/102).

---

I think Sears worked well last year. My vote would be for breakfast again.

Towards the start of the conference would be good as well, to help put faces to names so I can spot people in the DevZone.

Especially for those who don't resemble their abstract profile pictures:
[image]

Comment: Won't you be embarrassed when a Pacman ghost walks into the restaurant.

Comment: @DanielHoechst When a [Small Space Invader](http://spaceinvaders.wikia.com/wiki/Small_Invader) resembling an aquatic squid or [identicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon) comes in I think we can boast of how inclusive we are at SFSE.  I will buy them a suitable breakfast beverage and find them a place at the tables.

Comment: I'm working on my space invader costume :) Will change the avatar right away so that you're able to spot my melon! :)

Comment: Maybe I should limit the offer to the first two arrivals. The current NZD to USD exchange rate could make this an extremely expensive proposal.

Comment: I reckon I might actually be able to make one of these meetups for once! About damned time :)

Comment: @DanielBallinger, Obviously, I know nothing about 80s video game characters. We now have it set up! See my other answer.

Answer (score 2):

It was great to finally meet some faces and to catch up with some old dogs :)

[http://imgur.com/eP50pfJ](https://imgur.com/eP50pfJ)